# Is this enough to satisfy continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity

### Exercise:

> Prove that the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous for $x \geq 0$.

---

### Attempt 1: original

First, I prove that the $\Delta f(x) \to 0$:

$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}{[f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)]}$
$ = \lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}{[\sqrt{x+\Delta x} - \sqrt{x}]}$
$ = \sqrt{x+0} - \sqrt{x}$
$ = 0$

Then, I prove that the limit of $f(x + \Delta x)$ as $\Delta x \to 0$ is equal to $f(x)$:

$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}{f(x + \Delta x)} =^? f(x)$
$\longrightarrow \lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}{\sqrt{x + \Delta x}} =^? \sqrt{x}$
$\longrightarrow \sqrt{x + 0} =^? \sqrt{x}$
$\longrightarrow \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x}$

Is my attempt enough to prove the continuity of $f(x)$?

---

### Attempt 2: after @ClementC.'s comment

$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}{[f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)]}$
$ = \lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}{[\sqrt{x+\Delta x} - \sqrt{x}]}$
$ = \lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}{[(\sqrt{x+\Delta x} - \sqrt{x})\frac{\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x}}]}$
$ = \lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}{[\frac{x+\Delta x - x}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x}}]}$
$ = \lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}{[\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{x+\Delta x} + \sqrt{x}}]}$

**But at this point, I'm left with the same dilemma: I can't replace $\Delta x$ with $0$, so what do I do?**

---

I've been trying to use a similar method as the text in my book:
[image: 1]

Comment: You *are using* continuity of $f=\sqrt{}$ as soon as you write $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \sqrt{x+\Delta x} = \sqrt{x+0}$. So your proof is circular.

Comment: @ClementC. -- Oh, right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are using* continuity of $f=\sqrt{}$ as soon as you write $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\sqrt{x+\Delta x}-\sqrt{x}] = \sqrt{x+0}-\sqrt{x}$. So your proof is circular.

Moreover, it's not clear what the difference would be between your first and second step: for any fixed $x\geq 0$, proving $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)] = 0$ is equivalent to proving $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} f(x+\Delta x) = f(x)$.

This being said, let us give a proof of this continuity.

---

Fix any $x_0\geq 0$. For $h\in\mathbb{R}$ *(for the sake of well-definedness, we assume $h\in[-x_0, \infty)$*).

- If $x_0=0$:
  $$\lvert f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)\rvert^2 = 
  \sqrt{h}^2 = \lvert h\rvert \xrightarrow[h\to 0]{} 0
  $$
  so $f$ is continuous at $0$.
- If $x_0 > 0$: we have
  $$\lvert f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)\rvert = \lvert\sqrt{x_0+h}-\sqrt{x_0}\rvert
  = \sqrt{x_0}\cdot \left\lvert\sqrt{1+\frac{h}{x_0}}-1\right\rvert
  $$
  so it is sufficient to show that $f$ is continuous at $1$ (indeed, since $\frac{h}{x_0} \xrightarrow[h\to0]{}0$, this will imply that the second factor goes to $0$).

So let us do this:
$$
\lvert\sqrt{1+h}-1\rvert= \frac{\lvert \sqrt{1+h}^2-1^2\rvert}{\lvert\sqrt{1+h}+1\rvert}= \frac{\lvert h\rvert}{\lvert\sqrt{1+h}+1\rvert} \leq \lvert h\rvert\xrightarrow[h\to0]{}0
$$
proving continuity of $f$ at $1$, and therefore at any $x_0>0$ by the above discussion.

Comment: Why is it sufficient to show that $f$ is continuous at $1$?

Comment: Damn, that was deleted by mistake. Adding back this part.

Comment: @FineMan Is it clearer now?

Comment: Not quite. I think I don't understand the precise definition of continuity. I'm looking for some sources that explain it well. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Not that much -- the "baby Rudin" book may be a good reference, but I learnt from my teacher's lecture notes at the time. But basically, continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ means that $\lvert f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)\rvert \xrightarrow[h\to 0]{} 0$.

Comment: I'm still confused on when and when not to replace $\Delta x$ (or $h$). When I do it, it's a circular definition; but, when you do it, it's valid. :P

Comment: Oh, I did not replace $h$ by $0$ inside the function. I applied the squeeze theorem to something of the form $0\leq whatever \leq \lvert h\rvert h$, knowing that (by definition of $h\to0$) the RHS was converging to $0$.

Comment: I'm still not sure where the squeeze theorem was applied.

Comment: If $\lvert f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) \rvert\leq \vert h\rvert$ and $h\to 0$, the squeeze theorem guarantees that $\lvert f(x_0+h)-f(x_0) \rvert\to 0$.

Comment: Oh, you implicitly omitted $0 \leq \cdots$?

Comment: Yes, since the absolute value is non-negative by definition.

Comment: OK, that makes a lot more sense. I was failing to find the LHS of the squeeze. :)